# How to add the max age on caching for static files

Tags: python, caching, flask

I am doing a few tests about my website health in [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)

I had a low score due to `Leverage browser caching` since I hadn't added any max-age on headers response and it was 0. Now I have this in Python Flask:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.cache_control.max_age = 86400
    return response
```

The header response for the website:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=86400
```

But all the static files still have `max-age=0`. I read about Webassets on Python Flask, but I am not sure how to use it, since I didn't find a tutorial to make all the static files have the same cache-control. How can I continue to make the same as I did for the page?